# Range analysis of floating point values?

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, floating-point, fixed-point

I have an image processing program which uses floating point calculations. However, I need to port it to a processor which does not have floating point support in it. So, I have to change the program to use fixed point calculations. For that I need proper scaling of those floating point numbers, for which I need to know the range of all values, including intermediate values of the floating point calculations.

Is there a method where I just run the program and it automatically give me the range of all the floating point calculations in the program? Trying to figure out the ranges manually would be too cumbersome, so if there is some tool for doing it, that would be awesome!

Comment: Can't you use the soft-float implementation? I don't know about such tool you're asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some "measuring" replacement for your floating type, along these lines ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7ce45e496a09cc7)):

```
template<typename T>
class foo
{
    T val;

    using lim = std::numeric_limits<int>;

    static int& min_val() { static int e = lim::max(); return e; }
    static int& max_val() { static int e = lim::min(); return e; }

    static void sync_min(T e) { if (e < min_val()) min_val() = int(e); }
    static void sync_max(T e) { if (e > max_val()) max_val() = int(e); }

    static void sync(T v)
    {
        v = std::abs(v);
        T e = v == 0 ? T(1) : std::log10(v);
        sync_min(std::floor(e)); sync_max(std::ceil(e));
    }

public:
    foo(T v = T()) : val(v) { sync(v); }
    foo& operator=(T v) { val = v; sync(v); return *this; }

    template<typename U> foo(U v) : foo(T(v)) {}
    template<typename U> foo& operator=(U v) { return *this = T(v); }

    operator T&() { return val; }
    operator const T&() const { return val; }

    static int min() { return min_val(); }
    static int max() { return max_val(); }
};
```

to be used like

```
int main ()
{
    using F = foo<float>;
    F x;

    for (F e = -10.2; e <= 30.4; e += .2)
        x = std::pow(10, e);

    std::cout << F::min() << " " << F::max() << std::endl;  // -11 31
}
```

This means you need to define an alias (say, `Float`) for your floating type (`float` or `double`) and use it consistently throughout your program. This may be inconvenient but it may prove beneficial eventually (because then your program is more generic). If your code is already templated on the floating type, even better.

After this parametrization, you can switch your program to "measuring" or "release" mode by defining `Float` to be either `foo<T>` or `T`, where `T` is your `float` or `double`.

The good thing is that you don't need external tools, your own code carries out the measurements. The bad thing is that, as currently designed, it won't catch all intermediate results. You would have to define all (e.g. arithmetic) operators on `foo` for this. This can be done but needs some more work.

Comment: That is awesome. It is due to these kind of awesome features, I love C++ :)!

Answer (score 3):

It is not true that you cannot use floating point code on hardware that does not support floating point - the compiler will provide software routines to perform floating point operations - they just may be rather slow - but if it is fast enough for your application , that is the path of least resistance.

It is probably simplest to implement a fixed point data type class and have its member functions detect over/underflow as a debug option (because the checking will otherwise slow your code).

I suggest you look at [Anthony Williams' fixed-Point math C++ library](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/news/optimizing-applications-with-fixed-point-arithmetic.html).  It is in C++ and defines a `fixed` class with extensive function and operator overloading, so it can largely be used simply by replacing `float` or `double` in your existing code with `fixed`.  It uses `int64_t` as the underlying integer data type, with 34 integer bits and 28 fractional bits (34Q28), so is good for about 8 decimal places and a wider range than `int32_t`.

It does not have the under/overflow checking I suggested, but it is a good starting point for you to add your own.

On 32bit ARM this library performs about 5 times faster than software-floating point and is comparable in performance to ARM's VFP unit for C code.

Note that the `sqrt()` function in this library has poor precision performance for very small values as it looses lower-order bits in intermediate calculations that can be preserved. It can be improved by replacing it with the code the version I presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721022/how-to-improve-fixed-point-square-root-for-small-values).

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the compiler's ability to generate code for floating point emulation, but like you said, its too slow. That is why, I prefer fixed point there.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: fair enough, but that is not clear in your question,

Answer (score 2):

For self-contained C programs, you can use [Frama-C's value analysis](http://frama-c.com/try_out_value.html) to obtain ranges for the floating-point variables, for instance `h` below:

[image: value analysis on floating-point variable h]

And variable `g` computed from `h`:

[image: value analysis on floating-point variable g]

There is a specification language to describe the ranges of the inputs (information without which it is difficult to say anything informative). In the example above, I used that language to specify what function `float_interval` was expected to do:

```
/*@ ensures \is_finite(\result) && l <= \result <= u ; */
float float_interval(float l, float u);
```

Frama-C is easiest to install on Linux, with Debian and Ubuntu binary packages for a recent (but usually not the latest) version available from within the distribution.

If you could post your code, it would help telling if if this approach is realistic. If your code is C++, for instance (your question does not say, it is tagged with several language tags), then the current version of Frama-C will be no help as it only accepts C programs.

Comment: That is great. What I understood is that your tool is able to calculate the ranges without running the program, that is through static analysis/abstract interpretation. You showed example of individual variables, but is it also possible to consider all the floating point variables in the program collectively for the range. Secondly, can you also specify the input range of the variables? By input, I mean the value with which the variables are initialized.

Comment: @MetallicPriest I illustrated how your second question could be handled by changing the example in my answer, now including a call to a function `float_interval` of which the analyzer knows only the description `\is_finite(\result) && l <= \result <= u`.

Comment: @MetallicPriest For your first question, I have to point out that one of the advantages of this approach compared to, say, iavr's proposal is that you can observe the range of each computation and use the optimal representation for each. For instance, if your program multiplies two numbers in the [1.0 .. 256.0] range, it would help you infer that a 8Q8 * 8Q8 -> 16Q0 multiplication is best. iavr's proposal as currently described would only tell you that some numbers go up to 65025.

Comment: @MetallicPriest But if you really want a uniform representation for all variables, there are programatic ways to iterate on all states and variables and to gather lower and upper bounds that apply to all variables at all points of the program. One way would be to write your own Frama-C plug-in. The value analysis plug-in makes its results available for any other plug-in to use. The GUI is only taking advantage of this interface in my screenshots. Any other plug-in can access the same information through the same API.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. Your tool looks very impressive. Its amazing how much you can do with it without even running the program. I will give it a try for sure.